# cuda - gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated

Tags: software-installation, nvidia, gzip

I downloaded cuda toolkit from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads#linux)! I'm running on 32-bit Linux(Mint 17). I had to download `.run` file(the downloaded file name is

`cuda_6.5.14_linux_32.run-{09606fc1-f7a7-4b33-a22d-12b51c090f83}.dtapart`

After downloading, I made it executable(Properties -> Permissions -> Allow this ... ). When I ran it, it didn't work(nothing happen).

I tried installing it from terminal. I did `chmod +x <name>` and then 'bash '. But now it showed me this message:

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
Extraction failed.
Ensure there is enough space in /tmp and that the installation package is not corrupt
Signal caught, cleaning up
```

I searched the error but I couldn't find a solution.

My system info:

`32bit LinuxMint 17`

`lspci | grep -i nvidia` :

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce G 105M] (rev a1)

`uname -m && cat /etc/*release`:

```
i686
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

Comment: You have not posted df for /tmp AND I'd suggest redownloading from another source AND veryifying the checksum of the download.  Failing that, maybe a quick note to the provider of the package for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Files whose names are decorated with a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid) and the extension 'dtapart', such as this, are most likely partially downloaded files generated by the download manager [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/). If this is the case, the reason it could not be properly invoked is because it was an incomplete download.

You can either finish the download or delete it and restart the download from the beginning, and make sure it completes entirely, before running it as you have.